# Asking about arrangments

Tags: present-tense

I am little confused with one question which was in my test.

> "Are you seeing her at the university today?" - it was translation task and that answer was correct.

Present Continuous implies an arrangement?

If I ask *will you be seeing* it will mean I want to ask someone politely to do something for me e.g. *Will you be seeing ... today? I want you to give her gift for birthday*. Moreover Future Continuous conveys a repeated action (we are working together / studying together, so we will meet at some time at university).

And if I ask *Do you see her on Monday?*, in this case it will indicate timetales (for example we ask someone's tutor about his meeting with a student)?

And If I use `to be going to` construction it will indicate my companien has not fix an appointment yet,  so he isn't sure whether he will meet the person I am askinng about. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Anthony. This question is better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se]. I've voted to move it over there for you.

Comment: @DanBron, Hello, I would not mind it

Comment: Short Answer: Yes, present continuous implies a previous arrangement for a one-time event. Long Answer: Simple present implies a previous arrangement for recurring events. See [here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you have it mostly right:

> I am playing tennis today
>
> I play tennis every Thursday afternoon.

These indicate a future activity and a recurring activity, respectively.  However just because I say "I am playing tennis today" doesn't mean I don't play tennis *every* day.  Meanwhile:

> I will be playing tennis today

is much the same as the present continuous, although it adds an element of *intention* and also *simultaneity*.  There is a suggestion that something else might be happening at the same time (in the future) which is why I have to explain what I will be doing instead.

Finally:

> I am going to play tennis today

means much the same as "will be playing tennis".  Despite what many English lessons say, (in AmE at least) there is no real difference between "will" and "going to" in meaning or nuance:

> "The sun will rise tomorrow at 6 am." = "The sun is going to rise tomorrow at 6 am."
>
> "I will meet him later" = "I am going to meet him later."